# span background according to data value

Tags: css

I have a span class `cor` (color):

```
<span class="cor" data-c="red">red</span>
<span class="cor" data-c="green">green</span>
<span class="cor" data-c="blue">blue</span>
```

and cor style:

```
.cor{
 padding:5px;
 margin:5px;
}
```

What I want is the .cor `background-color` to be the color of the `data-c` element value. Can I style the .cor background based on the `data-c` value?

edit-------

it is not working:

```
 background-color: attr(data-c);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with **JQuery**

```js
$('.cor').each(function() {
  var color = $(this).data('c');
  $(this).css('background-color', color);
});
```

```css
.cor{
   padding:5px;
   margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="cor" data-c="red">red</span>
<span class="cor" data-c="green">green</span>
<span class="cor" data-c="blue">blue</span>
```

Comment: nice, it works fine! thank you friend!